# How to set canvas size?

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, ondraw

I have a class named SeatsPanel where I draw seats (using drawRect) in the onDraw method. The onDraw method uses Canvas as a parameter, but how do you set size of the Canvas? The reason why I'm asking this question is because this class is being inflated in another class. I know that the canvas has the default height and width of the phone, but I need to make it smaller. How can I do this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean you want to make the canvas smaller ? Normally the canvas size is managed by Android, and depends on the measured size of the View.

Comment: Ok, but how do I change the size of the View then? I'm confused, I just want to change the size of this class.

Comment: why do you need to inflate it? Any reason

Comment: Because I have another class where it extends Activity and this one extends View to draw on the screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've tried to implement a simple application that draws a black rect within the main activity, that is drawn pushing a button. For example, in the `MainActivity`:

```
    private Button button1;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v) {
             switch(v.getId()){
                case R.id.button:

                     LinearLayout ll=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
                     System.out.println(ll.getWidth()+" "+ll.getHeight());
                     LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ll.getWidth(),ll.getHeight());
                     YourView yourView = new YourView(getBaseContext());
                     yourView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                     ll.addView(yourView,params);
                    break;
             }

        }

    });

}
```

And in the `YourView` class:

```
    private Bitmap savedBitmap;
public YourView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    System.out.println(canvas.getWidth()+" "+canvas.getHeight());

    Paint textPaint = new Paint();
    textPaint.setARGB(255, 0, 0, 0);
    textPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.RIGHT);
    textPaint.setTextSize(11);
    textPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);

    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    System.out.println(canvas.getWidth());
    System.out.println(canvas.getHeight());

    canvas.drawRect(200, 20, 500, 100, textPaint);
}
```

The main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Push the button and draw a Rect" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />




<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I like this one, but sadly it doesn't solve the problem I have right now. I need to change the canvas size in the onDraw method.

Comment: When I use this method, the screen turns white... :/ I don't see the content of the onDraw method anymore.

Comment: I've tried to implement a small application that pushing a button, draws a rect into the linearLayout under the button, in the mainActivity. It works for me...

Comment: Can you also post the main.xml file so I can test your method. Thanx

Comment: I've edited the source code. This application change the canvas size from the activity, not from the onDraw...

Comment: Thanks, this works great, but is there any way to change the LinearLayout1 size after drawing the seats? I want to use a variable to count how high the row is and then use that variable to give/change the height of the Canvas/View... Is there any way to do this?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10322/discussion-between-xonarial-and-v4l3ri4)

Answer (score 3):

Might not be applicable in your case, but this works for me

```
Bitmap animation = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), resourceId, mBitmapOptions); //Get a bitmap from a image file

// Create a bitmap for the part of the screen that needs updating.
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(animation.getWidth(), animation.getHeight(), BITMAP_CONFIG);
bitmap.setDensity(DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
```

This sets the canvas to the size of the bitmap

Comment: This won't help, I need to use a better method to solve the issue.